# Screencapture and Save to JPG, Actionscript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have created a flash file which capable of creating movie clips by clicking each of respected buttons. What I want to do is, after I positioning all of these movie clips created, I would like to save it into JPEG or PNG image file. I have created a save button and named it "save_page_btn". I tried to find tutorial using AS 2.0 but it is seems to no avail. I have no basic in AS 3.0. Can anyone help me to find this solution.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

**ActionScript 2 :**

For ActionScript 2, you have to save your image using a server side script, like a PHP script which I used in [my answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27887378/actionscript-2-0-screen-capture/27911528#27911528).

**ActionScript 3 :**

For ActionScript 3, things are more easy because [`FileReference`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) give us the ability to [save](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#save%28%29) a file directly to our machine.

So for you case, you want to save your image as a jpg or a png file, which you can do using the `JPGEncoder` and `PNGEncoder` included in the [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) library. You can download it from [here](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/downloads) and then include it in your project from : **File > ActionScript Settings ... > Library Path** and then press the **Browse to SWC file** tab and select your as3corelib.swc downloaded file. Then you can do like this :

```
// in my stage, I have 2 buttons : btn_save_jpg and btn_save_png, and a MovieClip : movie_clip

import com.adobe.images.JPGEncoder;
import com.adobe.images.PNGEncoder;

btn_save_jpg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save_img);
btn_save_png.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save_img);

function save_img(e:MouseEvent):void {

    // verify which button is pressed using its name
    var is_jpg:Boolean = (e.currentTarget.name).substr(-3, 3) == 'jpg'; 
    // you can also write it : var is_jpg:Boolean = e.currentTarget === btn_save_jpg;   

    // create our BitmapData and draw within our movie_clip MovieClip
    var bmd_src:BitmapData = new BitmapData(movie_clip.width, movie_clip.height)
        bmd_src.draw(movie_clip);

    if(is_jpg){     
        // if it's the btn_save_jpg button which is pressed, so create our JPGEncoder instance
        // for the btn_save_png button, we don't need to create an instance of PNGEncoder 
        // because PNGEncoder.encode is a static function so we can call it directly : PNGEncoder.encode()
        var encoder:JPGEncoder = new JPGEncoder(90);
        // 90 is the quality of our jpg, 0 is the worst and 100 is the best
    }

    // get encoded BitmapData as a ByteArray
    var stream:ByteArray = is_jpg ? encoder.encode(bmd_src) : PNGEncoder.encode(bmd_src);

    // open the save dialog to save our image 
    var file:FileReference = new FileReference();
        file.save(stream, 'snapshot_' + getTimer() + (is_jpg ? '.jpg' : '.png'));

}
```

If you have a question about the AS3 ( or even the AS2 ) code, don't hesitate to ask it using the comments area.

Hope that can help.